# Adicionar uma coluna com o número da linha no resultado do select

Tags: sql, oracle

Como eu posso adicionar o número da linha do resultado do select em uma coluna adicional?

Por exemplo:

```
select e.ds_estados  
  from estados e
```

Esse select me retornaria os estados cadastrados

```
    AC
    AL
    AM
    ...
    TO
```

Gostaria que ao lado do estado retornasse o número da linha junto

```
    1  -  AC
    2  -  AC
    3  -  AC
    ...
    27  - TO
```

Answer (score 2):

Obrigado Jeferson Almeida!

Acabei descobrindo outra maneira de fazer isso também, para quem se interessar, segue o código:

```
select rownum linha, 
       a.estado estado 
from (select b.estado     
        from estados b) a
```

Answer (score 1):

Para isso você pode utilizar a função `row_number()` segue abaixo o exemplo de como utiliza-lá, no caso eu fiz ordenando pela coluna `e.ds_estados`

```
select  row_number() over (order by e.ds_estados) linha, e.ds_estados  
from estados e
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS position, ds_estados FROM estados, (SELECT @i:=0) AS t WHERE 1
```